# access real-time input in java

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author K
 */
public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame2
 */
public NewJFrame2() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    convertB = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    box1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    precB = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    box2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    tf1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tf2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("CS12MP2: IEEE754");
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 250));

    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));

    convertB.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    convertB.setText("Convert to:");

    box1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    box1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "DEC", "IEEE" }));
    box1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            box1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    precB.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    precB.setText("Precision:");

    box2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    box2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Single", "Double", "L" }));
    box2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            box2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tf1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tf1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Output");

    tf2.setEditable(false);
    tf2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tf2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(tf1)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(convertB)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(box1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                    .addComponent(precB)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(box2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(tf2))
            .addGap(0, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(convertB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(box1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(precB)
                .addComponent(box2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(tf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 280, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private String hex="";

private void box1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    javax.swing.JComboBox jb = ( javax.swing.JComboBox)evt.getSource();
    Object selected = jb.getSelectedItem();
    hex = tf1.getText();
    if(selected.toString().equals("DEC")){

         //   tf2.setText(hex);
    }
    else if(selected.toString().equals("IEEE")){
            //   tf2.setText("G");
    }
}                                    

private void box2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    javax.swing.JComboBox jm = ( javax.swing.JComboBox)evt.getSource();
    Object selected = jm.getSelectedItem();
    if(selected.toString().equals("Single")){
          //  tf2.setText("Single");
    }
    else if(selected.toString().equals("Double")){
              // tf2.setText("Double");
    }
    else if(selected.toString().equals("Double")){
             //  tf2.setText("Double");
    }
}                                    

private void tf1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
   // String text = tf1.getText();
   // tf1.selectAll();
    //tf1.getDocument();

}                                   

private void tf2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]){
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JComboBox box1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox box2;
private javax.swing.JLabel convertB;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JLabel precB;
private javax.swing.JTextField tf1;
private javax.swing.JTextField tf2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

what should I add on my codes so that I can access what's typed in the `TextField` in real-time and output the answer in real-time.

Comment: What's wrong with the previous answers that you've being provided with?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html